# Cant install php on Apache & Windows 7 64

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache, added

```
LoadModule php5_module c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:\php"
```

to httpd file, set up php.ini file (im using thread safe 5.5.10 x64 version), but when im trying to run apache im getting message "the requested operation has failed".

Comment: I use Apache on Linux, so I'm admittedly not an expert. However, I noticed your slashes are switched between LoadModule and PHPIniDir. Is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: It is as i was instructed from a book which im using to learn php

Comment: Ok...let's see. Are you using Apache 2.4, and does the specified DLL exist at that location ("C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll")? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736106/php-5-5-5-not-working-with-apache-2-4-7) may also help.

Comment: Mentioned file exist in php directory but my apache version is 2.2.25, so that would be the reason i cant get this stuff working ?

Comment: Hrm...is there also a "php5apache2_2.dll" file in the directory? If so, try that.

Comment: theres only 2_4.dll in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user ChrisForrence suggested i was attempting to run incompatible versions of apache and php. Finally, i was able to find detailed tutorial on youtube here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17qhikHv5hY which taught me ho to install apache and php (there's another movie by same user about latter).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use forward slashes
2. Enclose the path to the dll in quotes
3. Double check the paths and directory names

   ```
   LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   PHPIniDir "C:/php"
   ```

Comment: I did this, but to no avail