# Where to set php module version in apache 2.4.7

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Having looked in /etc/php/apache2/php.ini, /etc/apache2/apache.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/php.conf I cannot locate where to load my newly built php? There are no LoadModule directives anywhere, and I can't find any answers on the web. Has something new changed in 2.4.7?

Comment: *newly built php* have you builded it with make and make install?

Comment: @donald123 I used phpbrew. i have the new build running fine in CLI.

Comment: i don't know phpbrew ... i have had simular problems to update php on ubuntu when i basicly installed it via apt-get install apache2 php5 on ubuntu / debian ... when it helps you i can post you a way to build php on your own by using apache mysql installed via apt-get

Comment: Thank you, but I have a libphp-5.3.29.so after compilation, so I can use that. I noticed however, that apache seems to jump between this version and 5.5 which is very very odd.

Comment: I think I have found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22571798/1658296 I am busy testing this.

Comment: yes it can be your solution ... the problem is, when you install apache the threaded modul isn't installed to ... so first you must install via apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev and then you can compile your php as so modul